# Почему при использовании where результат содержит ссылку на исходный массив?

Tags: c#, linq

Допустим у меня есть массив `List<List<string>> first_mas`, на котором я провожу выборку

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
result = first_mas.Where(d => d[0] == "1").First();
```

Если допустим я потом в `result` удалю несколько элементов, то и в исходном `first_mas` удалятся эти элементы. Как я понимаю это из-за того что `result` содержит ссылку на `first_mas` или дело в другом? Можно как то указать чтобы результат был самостоятельным массивом (без ссылки на исходный)? Или только вручную создавать промежуточный и копировать туда?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Where` лишь фильтрует исходных список. Логично, что результат ссылается на оригинал.

> Можно как то указать чтобы результат был самостоятельным массивом (без
>   ссылки на исходный)?

Например, так:

```
List<string> result = first_mas.Where(d => d[0] == "1").First().ToList();
```

Или:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>(first_mas.Where(d => d[0] == "1").First());
```

Comment: ну или еще так `var result = new List<string>(first_mas.First(d => d[0] == "1"));`

Answer (score 4):

Потому что List< T> - ссылочный тип, и ссылка, указывающая на result, ссылается на соответствующий элемент списка first_mas